# Leaflet map markers clearLayers() before new position data

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am working on a Leaflet map with markers.I am getting marker latlong data from a file that is updated every 5 seconds with new position data for about 100 markers.

I then use switch to break the markers into 2 groups which are represented on the map with different icons.

My problem is that each time new position data is updated new markers are created but the old markers remain, so before long there is a trail of markers and the map becomes very slow.

I want to clear the old marker each time new markers are created and have tried using the clearLayers() function to no effect. There are no errors, but the markers remain. I have moved the clearLayers() to other levels in the code to either no effect or completely removing all markers including any new markers.

geojson.js

```
     async function getData() {

        const response = await fetch('../../Export.log');
        var data = await response.text();
        var formatted = JSON.parse('[' + data.trim().replace(/\n/g, ',') + ']')
        var enemyForces = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
        var alliedForces = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
        alliedForces.clearLayers();
        enemyForces.clearLayers();

        for (var i = 0; i < formatted.length; i++){
            var unit = formatted[i];
            var coalition = unit.coalition;
            var Lat = unit.Lat;
            var Long = unit.Long;
            var LatLong = [Lat, Long];
            var LongLat = [Long, Lat];
            var name = unit.name;
            var ID = unit.ID;
        

            switch (coalition) {
                case "Enemies":

                    L.marker([Lat, Long], {icon: enemyIcon}).bindPopup(name + "<br>" + coalition + "<br>" + ID).addTo(enemyForces);

                    break;
                case "Allies":

                    L.marker([Lat, Long], {icon: alliedIcon}).bindPopup(name + "<br>" + coalition + "<br>" + ID).addTo(alliedForces);

            } // End switch
        
        } // End for

    }
        
        getData();
        setInterval(getData, 5000);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <title>Test Map</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>

    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='map'></div>
<script src="js/geojson.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

map.js

```
// Start Map
var map = L.map('map').setView([33.5, -117.0], 7);

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox/light-v9',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(map);

var unitIcon = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
        iconSize:     [32, 37],
        iconAnchor:   [0, 0],
        popupAnchor:  [0, -5]
    }
});

var alliedIcon = new unitIcon({iconUrl: 'img/ally.png'}),
    enemyIcon = new unitIcon({iconUrl: 'img/enemy.png'});


function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
// does this feature have a property named popupContent?
if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
}
}
```

Export.log

```
{"ID" : 50, "name" : "Blue1", "coalition" : "Allies", "Lat" : 33.331, "Long" : -117.162, "Alt" : 10.160897, "heading" : 6.283185}
{"ID" : 51, "name" : "Red1", "coalition" : "Enemies", "Lat" : 33.374, "Long" : -116.835, "Alt" : 0.045466, "heading" : 4.879922}
{"ID" : 52, "name" : "Blue2", "coalition" : "Allies", "Lat" : 33.783, "Long" : -117.228, "Alt" : 6.703342, "heading" : 3.078192}
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `getData`, you're creating a brand new `enemyForces` and `alliedForces`.  You're adding it to the map.  When you run the switch statement, if modifies the `enemyForces` and `alliedForces` of the current function closure, but does not affect those variables from previous function closures.  Move those variable declarations outside the function.

```js
// move these definitions outside of your function
var enemyForces = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
var alliedForces = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

async function getData(){

  ...

  enemyForces.clearLayers();
  alliedForces.clearLayers();

  for (...){

    ...

    switch (coalition) {

      case "Enemies":
        L.marker([Lat, Long], {icon: enemyIcon}).bindPopup(...).addTo(enemyForces);
        break;

      case "Allies":
        L.marker([Lat, Long], {icon: alliedIcon}).bindPopup(...).addTo(alliedForces);

    } // end switch
  } // end for
 
}
```

#### Edit:

Changed answer.  Using `clearLayer` should be sufficient without needing to call `remove()`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited my code above to reflect the changes I made based on your suggestions. When I tried the map I do not get any markers with this code.

Comment: error message: ``dcs-geojson.js:10 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined``

Comment: Updated code again moving var out of loop.  Not getting an error message and the markers are showing up again, but the old markers are still not being removed.

Comment: very strange.  perhaps you can create a working sample of the problem with a codepen or codesandbox?

Comment: on second thought, `clearLayer` should be sufficient, you don't need `.remove().`  This is a closure issue.  See my edited answer, and see if that helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately the key to the whole issue is the updated markers which requires a program on my local machine to update the position data. I dont know a way I could recreate that on another machine in order for the script to work. I could put static data, but then there wouldn't be any new marker positions to show the trail of old positions.

Comment: nevermind, check out my edited answer, this is a closure issue

Comment: I tried and got this error. ``leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: t.addLayer is not a function``

Comment: that's strange. .addLayer` is called as part of the `addTo` functions, I'm not sure why it would be undefined.  perhaps you can post a working example with some sample data, even sample data should be enough to diagnose that problem.  `

Comment: I added the other 2 files and a sample data set. The error only showwed up when I moved ``var enemyForces = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
var alliedForces = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);`` outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide as follows ;

```
clearLayersByType(type) {
  if(type == 'enemyForces') {
    this.enemyForces ? this.enemyForces.clearLayers() : null ;
  }
}
```